# Sanitizing URLs being inserted into a WordPress MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, sanitization, mysql-real-escape-string

I am writing a plugin for Wordpress, where I have my own custom table to store the relevant data being pulled from a remote API. One of the elements I need to store is a URL, which is a TEXT field within my database.

Since I have seen numerous comments saying not to use standard `mysql_` or `mysqli_` functions in Wordpress plugins, I am wondering what is the best way to escape the URL before I insert it? Is using [esc_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_url/) sufficient enough or is there anything else I should do prior?

```
    case "Create":
    {
        $tag = $_POST['product_tag'];
        $name = $_POST['product_name'];
        $asin = $_POST['product_id'];

        $response = getPrice("com", $asin);

        $result = $wpdb->insert( $table_name, array(
            'tag' => $tag,
            'name' => $name,
            'asin' => $asin,
            'price' => $response['price'],
            'url' => esc_url($response['url'])
        ));

        if ($result !== FALSE)
            echo "Successfully inserted new Amazon Product.";
        else
            echo "An Error occurred.";

        break;
    }
```

Comment: +1 @tadmsn's answer. Also look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php and FILTER_VALIDATE_URL filter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally you'd just insert a URL as-is in your database and only be concerned with security issues when presenting it. This, of course, presumes you're doing things correctly like you are here where you've explicitly called the `insert` function with data sent in as an associative array.

The real risk is when people bypass WPDB and insert things directly, and often badly by using string concatenation.

You *should* call [`esc_url`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url) when *displaying* these values. As you may change what's an allowed URL from time to time, limiting them or opening them up as your needs change, it's best to keep them raw in the database and prepare them for display on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense! I guess sanitization is more of a concern with data that has been provided by the end user. As this is coming directly from the Amazon API and gets inserted, I will just use esc_url for the display instead.

Comment: You do filtering and pre-proessing like trimming off leading and trailing spaces on user data, then escape it for whatever context you're saving it in. MySQL uses one approach, CSV another, and JSON another still. HTML is just another context, you use methods for that context when necessary, like `htmlspecialchars`. It's good you're using WPDB properly, that solves 99% of the security problems out of the gate. The only other thing you might do with API generated data is verify it's actually a URL rather than some empty string or an error message.